# AngularJS Formly ui-mask: Removing input mask characters for model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phone-number, input-mask

I have an input mask set up on a 10-digit phone number field in my Formly form using AngularJS: just masking the input with dashes: xxx-xxx-xxxx. The dashes are correctly displaying on the page, but the Formly model value for the field retains the dashes. How can I configure the form field to ignore the mask characters (dashes)? The model value should be:

```
phoneNumber: '4838884747'
```

not

```
phoneNumber: '483-888-4747'
```

I haven't gotten a formatter to work yet. Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = "483-888-4747";
var s2 = s.split("-").join('');
console.log(s2);
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - String.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/join)